# My Android APP freezes after a day or two but OS is still working

Tags: android, listener, freeze

We have an Android App which needs to run all day, the issue is that sometimes after several days it freezes where the buttons cannot be clicked.  We are able to see our Apps UI but none of the buttons are clickable.

At First i thought the whole OS was frozen but I was able to click on the Back and Home native Android buttons.  This is telling me that something is freezing within the App but not the OS itself. There is also NO message of App not responding when I click on it, its just completely frozen.

There are some devices connected via OTG USB hub like credit card reader, scale and printer in case that helps.

I dont know where to begin to look, and whats strange its sometimes hard to replicate, sometimes it works after 24-48 hours and sometimes it doesnt. But it has happened a few times already after a weekend of no interaction.

Could a Button click listener just stop responding for some reason based on duration? is there something in the code I have to do to keep a button listener awake for over 24 hours?

Any suggestions would be great

Thank you

Comment: Run app in debug mode (from PC) and when app freeze attach the debugger block main thread and you can see on which function thread will be stopped.

Comment: Are you using a service to communicate with the USB device?

Comment: Perhaps this is to obvious but, do you have a log of when you're app freezes?